# First-class cricketer who played before WW 1 and after WW2

Tags: cricket, trivia

I remember someone asking me about this. Is there any first-class cricketer who played before WW1 and after WW2 ?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, CK Nayudu played first-class cricket in India for an amazing 47 years, starting in 1916 (source: http://blog.thecricketer.com/?p=20215)

Other than that, I can't find anyone on Cricinfo who would have played in the span you're talking about (last match summer of 1914, next match summer of 1946). A lot of players played to the start of WW2, but first-class cricket was then suspended for the duration of the war.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are referring to [Bill Ashdown](http://www.espncricinfo.com/england/content/player/8793.html) whose first-class career spanned 1914-1947.

His Cricinfo profile mentions:

> He is the only man to have played first-class cricket in England before the First World War and after the Second.

I could also find one other player, [D.B. Deodhar](http://www.espncricinfo.com/india/content/player/28036.html), whose first-class career spanned 1911-1947.